# BLE Just Works method in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I'm working with `BLE`. When phone and `BLE` are in connecting state, that popup will show.
How to disable / hide Bluetooth Pairing Request popup? I've search about Just Works method, but I dont know how to implement that. Is Just Works method implemented in `BLE` firmware or implemented in `iOS` code ?

Comment: If your peripheral requires encryption then the user will be prompted for a passcode to pair (bond).  This cannot be avoided.  If no encryption is required then no bonding occurs and there will be no prompt.

Comment: so if I want to prevent popup, I must remove required encryption from BLE peripheral not from ios code? @Paulw11

Comment: That is correct.